# Fiber bundle of real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^d$ over $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

(1) Does there exist

and

(2) how many do they exist,

of a nontrivial fiber bundle $N^{d+1}$ of real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^d$ over $S^1$?

$N^{d+1}= S^1 \ltimes \mathbb{R}P^d$ so that
$$
\mathbb{R}P^d \hookrightarrow N^{d+1} \rightarrow S^1
$$

(what exactly is this fibration construction?)

Comment: Given any self-homeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^n$ you can form the [mapping torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_torus) $M_\varphi$. This fibres over $S^1$ with fibre $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and gives you a bundle. I'd turn this into an answer but $(1)$ I don't know how to say much about the classification of these gadgets, and $(2)$ you need to specify what you want: by 'fibre bundle' do you mean locally trivial map or projective bundle (these latter objects should be classified by $\pi_1(BPO_{n+1}=\pi_0PO_{n+1}$. Again I'm the wrong person to ask about this).

Comment: @Tyrone: I think you are too modest...